# What is the difference between a virus and virion

Tags: virology

What is the difference between a virus and virion.  Correct me if i am wrong but i think that one can simply say that " virus outside a cell is called a virion" and that this stage is used to go from one cell to another

Comment: A quick google search of "virion" reveals the following: "the complete, infective form of a virus outside a host cell, with a core of RNA or DNA and a capsid."
This article is interesting too: http://www.virology.ws/2010/07/22/the-virus-and-the-virion/
Your definition is basically correct, but keep in mind that the viral particle itself never enters the host. It merely attaches to the host cell and inserts its genetic material.

Comment: @Astrolamb you're correct, except that whether the viral particle enters the host or not will depend on the virus.

Comment: Right, I'd forgotten about enveloped viruses. However, "the complete, infective form of a virus" which has an envelope includes said envelope, and since the envelope doesn't enter the cell, I argue that the capsid is not the entirety of the viral particle in that case. I suppose I'm arguing semantics at this point though :P